# Appveyor CI build uses .NET lower than current

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, appveyor

Having the project which uses **.NET 7** target package:

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

In Visual Studio 2022 it builds normally without any error.
Also have GitHub actions that are also building without any error.

However when it comes to **ci.appveyor.com** it couldn't build and throws these errors.

[image]

Could you please advise what could cause such errors? And why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These errors were fixed by changing Visual Studio build worker image. Also, I updated my solution version of Visual Studio which supports .NET 7.
[image]